# memory management issue with NSIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management

So currently I am attempting to save an indexPath and access it, yet I keep receiving the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, and when I use the Analyze tool in xcode, it says that the value stored to my indexPath during its initialization is never read. Can anybody help and tell me what's going wrong here?

Method to set indexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSURL *requestURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"URL"];

//The request
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:requestURL];

request.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:indexPath,@"indexPath", nil];

[request setDelegate:self];    

[request startAsynchronous];   
[requestURL release];
[request release];
}
```

Method to access indexPath:

```
-(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{

UIImage *foodImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[request responseData]];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [request.userInfo objectForKey:@"indexPath"];

FoodDescription *detailViewController = [[FoodDescription alloc] initWithNibName:@"FoodDescription" bundle:nil];

// pass the food
detailViewController.aFood = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[_foodArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
detailViewController.foodPicture = foodImage;
detailViewController.restaurantName = _restaurantName;

// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're allocating a NSIndexPath, and then you're writing over it with your next statement. What is worse, you've leaked the memory allocated in the first statement. This is probably what the static analyzer was picking up on. What causes your crash is that you're attempting to release the object that overwrote the object from the first statement. Since it's already autoreleased, this *will* lead to a crash.

Just use:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [request.userInfo objectForKey:@"indexPath"];
```

and get rid of the release statement. You should be good.

Comment: well you've fixed the problem with the indexPath, but its still crashing for some reason. I think it has to do with the userInfo dictionary, but do you have any idea off the top of your head why I would still be getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS? I changed the indexPath code to your suggestion and got rid of the [indexPath release]...

Comment: @derek.lo Does your crash still occur in the same place? You shouldn't crash just for accessing `[request.userInfo objectForKey:@"indexPath"];` (though it could conceivably return nil).

Comment: I've edited my post with the full method where the crash occurs. Could it be the way that I am transferring objects from one view to another??

Comment: @derek.lo You shouldn't be releasing your `request` because it's autoreleased. But there's one other thing I'm wondering about: If `request` is autoreleased, and you're about to perform an asynchronous task with it, then I think you'd want to actually retain it until you receive notification that the task has completed.

Comment: you nailed it. Thanks so much. But I would like a follow up on whether we should be retaining the request or not until it's released. Could it hurt to call [request retain] as long as you are sure to release it either in requestDidSucceed or requestDidFail? Again, thanks so much for the help

Comment: @derek.lo I'm willing to go to chat with you on this. Let me know.

Comment: sounds good to me. I'm relatively new to stackoverflow so I don't really know how to start a chat...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9837/discussion-between-trudyscousin-and-derek-lo)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you allocate a new object, and store it into `indexPath`. Then, you *overwrite* this newly allocated index path with the one you previously stored in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Therefore, your newly allocated index path is lost, and you'll get an error.

What's more, you then attempt to release this object you stored in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, without "owning" it in the first place, so your app crashes.